# Ordering (sorting) from URL in django-rest-framework-filters with ComplexFilterBackend

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.8, django-rest-framework-filters

Are there ability to Ordering result with [djangorestframework-filters ComplexFilterBackend](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#configuring-complexfilterbackend) from URL?

DRF OrderingFilter is not worked with standart examples for djangorestframework-filters v.1.0.0.dev2.

My code with default order_by in query_set:

- Filter class:

```
from models import Template

class TemplateFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Template
        fields = {
            'id': '__all__',
            'status': '__all__',
            'name' : '__all__',
            'parent_id' : '__all__',
            }
```

- View:

```
from serializers import TemplateListSerializer
from models import Template
from filters import TemplateFilter

class TemplateListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    filter_class = TemplateFilter
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Template.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        self.serializer_class = TemplateListSerializer
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

How I can to change this code for ordering (sort) response from URL Request?
I want to see record with parent_id=guid first.

My input url for Django:
`GET /api/templates/?filters=(parent_id__isnull%3DTrue)%7C(parent_id%3Dguid)%26(ordering%3Dparent_id)&page=1`
Decoded:
`/api/templates/?filters=(parent_id__isnull=True)|(parent_id=guid)&(ordering=parent_id)&page=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer -  mandatory set two backend filters:

- First - for search, ComplexFilterBackend
- Second - for ordering, OrderingFilter

  ```
   from serializers import TemplateListSerializer
   from models import Template
   from filters import TemplateFilter
   from rest_framework import filters
   from rest_framework_filters.backends import ComplexFilterBackend

   class TemplateListView(ListCreateAPIView):
       filter_class = TemplateFilter

       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           self.queryset = Template.objects.all()
           self.serializer_class = TemplateListSerializer
           self.filter_backends = [ComplexFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
           self.ordering_fields = ['parent_id', 'name']
           self.ordering = ['parent_id']
           return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  ```